# Is there any way to restore visual studio files of a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am working on visual studio 2010.
I have done some changes in files and then I have closed the visual studio.
But now I want to restore the project, means I want to undo the previous changes.
lets say first version is version1 after changes this it becomes version2. I save these changes and close the visual studio. now I want version1 instead of version2.

So is there any way to restore the project in visual studio or on the basis of history I can get the the old project.

Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Moral - version control is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your code in under [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control): nope, there is not!

It's too late now, but setting up a [git](http://git-scm.com/) repository on your local machine is very easy (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)) and will save you that kind of problems in the future.